# How to send data to another c++ class

Tags: c++

let me explain what I would like to do. I have a vector of numbers (for example 1,2,3) that are in class A. I want a different class (class B) to read these vector of numbers and do some extra functionality from them numbers (I do not want to modify the numbers, just read them and act based on the number it reads).

The problem is that class A actually does some processing to get these numbers. I am just trying to understand the best way to code this problem and at the moment I am thinking of doing the following:

1) have a method in class A that stores the numbers 1,2,3 into a .txt file
2) class B reads from the .txt file and uses these numbers to do extra functionality.

Can anyone else think of a better method than this? Ideally i do not want to store to a .txt file as it is slow but cannot think of a better way.

Thank.

Comment: What about a function in class `A` which will return (maybe a reference to) the vector of numbers? Come on, this is the first thing you learn about classes. Another option is making the vector public, but then it can also be modified from outside `A`. Writing to a file is not even close to any solution you should think about for this problem.

Comment: Rather than A returning a (reference to) the vector, it should probably return `const_iterator`s to the beginning and end of the vector, so B can access (but not modify) the contents.

Comment: Can you post some code of your situation? Which shows the whole problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class A
{
  public:
    const std::vector<int>&  get_numbers(void) const
    {
      return vector_of_numbers;
    }
  private:
    std::vector<int> vector_of_numbers;
};

class B
{
  public:
    void process_numbers(A other)
    {
      const std::vector<int>& numbers = A.get_numbers();
      // process the numbers;
    }
};
```